# autosave html page every 5 minutes

Tags: html

I have to save a web page as .html file every five minutes. How can I do this? The html address will be like http://`<ipaddress`>:8080 where ipaddress is the ip address of my embedded device that is running a web server.

I want this to work in either Windows or Ubuntu.

Kindly clarify.

Comment: Any specific technology requirements? An easy solution would be a cron entry.

Comment: How would you like to accomplish this? What programming language?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the .NET framework, you can use `WebClient.DownloadString` to download the file, and you can throw this into a Console app and set up an item in Task Scheduler on a server for every 5 minutes.

Comment: I would like a utility that runs in unix and can take the html address as input and dumps the html contents to a new html file every time its executed. This utility can then be executed as a cron job to dump the html contents every 5 mins.

Comment: I tried using wget but it didnt work out properly. I tested wget using www.google.com as input but when I gave my html address which looks like "http://10.78.3.182:8080/dynamic/action?Page=info&Action=get", its not working in wget.

Comment: Can you post the wget output? I think it's the best choice

Comment: Try to put the URL in quotes; the shell may get confused by the ampersand.